# No correct centering when a line break is used

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-breaking

I have a `centering` environment inside a `figure`. In this environment, I have a text written in a `footnotesize` style. If I make a line break (`\\`) in the text, then the text is not centered correctly anymore.

Can anyone tell me why the text is not centered correctly?

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \noindent   
    \begin{centering}     
      \caption[HTTP-Polling]{HTTP-Polling}
      \label{fig:polling}
      \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{images/polling}       
      \par
      \footnotesize Quelle: Heise Zeitschriftenverlag, 06. März 2012\\http://www.heise.de/developer/imgs/06/6/7/6/2/3/3/Polling-61cb54a128001c08.png
    \end{centering}     
\end{figure}
```

Comment: `\centering` is not an environment, but a command. Use `\centering` instead of `\begin{centering}` and remove `\end{centering}`.

Comment: Or you could use `\begin{center} ... \end{center}`, although this would introduce additional vertical spacing, which you can redefine by first setting, e.g., `\topsep=0pt`.

Comment: \centering needs to be surrounded by braces (otherwise you center the entire rest of the document) and when it's surrounded by braces, it has the same problem of not centering the second line.

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned in a comment there exists a directive called `\centering` that turns on "centering" from now on until the end of the current group. Technically speaking any command can turned into an environment (whether it makes sense or not) by simply using the command name without backslash as the envioronment name. The begin/end of the environment forms a group and the command is executed within its scope.

For directives that can make sense, e.g., `\begin{itshape} ... \end{itshape}` makes perfect sense and in some cases is preferable over `{\itshape ...}`. However, `\begin{textbf}{...}  ... \end{textbf}` does not as the `\textbf` only operates on its argument, so the body of the environment doesn't serve any purpose.

Now coming back to your code: if a directive like `\centering` is used as an environment it is important to understand what happens at the end of this environment: nothing other than a group is closed ie the scope ends. That means what you have coded is equivalent of `{\centering ...}` without a final `\par`. But `\centering` operates only when the paragraph end is sensed (a `\\` is really doing a par break internally) and by the time the final `\par` is seen (which is inside `\end{figure}` the `\end{centering}` was executed and changed the setting from centering back to normal justified settings. To make things like `\centering` work many environments such as the floats or the `\parbox` etc contain implicit `\par` commands at their end to ensure that the final paragraph is finished with its current setting prior to closing the current group. But here this comes too late.

Therefore to fix this you would need to include a `\par` or empty line before `\end{centering}` or just use `\centering` (which is the better approach here) with the scope being the whole figure environment.

Comment: Didn't you mean `textbf` instead of `bftext`? :)

Comment: @DenisBitouzé  yes, thanks - now fixed